# neshan service API key just in debug mode work

Tags: android, kotlin, neshan-map, neshan-platform

my neshan service API key just in debug work, but in release give me 480 error why?
my license and my service API key is from same account.

Answer (score 1):

in order to publish your app , you have to change your release api key as you mentioned you are using same for both debug and release.

Your release key must be different from debug key.

check this :

https://neshan.blog/neshan-maps-android-sdk-intro-hntmb8edjg5r

hope this help you then just vote this answer.